# Prometheus: How can I multiply a vector by the average of another vector

Tags: prometheus, promql

## Situation

I have a counter with values from a power meter (KWh since it was installed). On my Grafana dashboard I like to show how much money was spend on electric power during the given time range.

Doing this with a fixed price per KWh is easy: `increase(loxone_values{control="Stromverbrauch Zähler"}[$__range]) * 0.22`

I can show the last value with a "Stat" in Grafana and get the amount of money spend.

## Problem

Obviously this fails if the price per KWh changes, which is does every hour in my case. I have a second metric that holds the current price. I like to multiply the KWh by the average price.

I think I can do this with `group_left` but failed to construct a working query.

My first approach `increase(loxone_values{control="Stromverbrauch Zähler"}[$__range]) * group_left avg(loxone_values{control="Strompreis aktuell"})` which gives a parse error.

It looks like `group_left` needs something to  match the vectors. But there is no common tag (beside `instance` but that might change in the future).

Anyway I gave that a try but `increase(loxone_values{control="Stromverbrauch Zähler"}[$__range]) * on (instance) group_left avg(loxone_values{control="Strompreis aktuell"})` gives me an empty result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

`increase(loxone_values{control="Stromverbrauch Zähler"}[$__range]) * scalar(avg(loxone_values{control="Strompreis aktuell"}))`

Explanation:

You can multiply an instant vector by an instant vector with exactly the same labels and label values or by a scalar. The result(s) of `increase(loxone_values{control="Stromverbrauch Zähler"}[$__range])` must have labels, whereas `avg(loxone_values{control="Strompreis aktuell"})` will return one instant vector with no labels. Using `scalar` converts the instant vector to a scalar and all results of `increase(loxone_values{control="Stromverbrauch Zähler"}[$__range])` will be multiplied by that, irrelevant of their labels.